# Why does my ARM template, fail to create authorization rules consistently?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have created an ARM template for deploying Azure Service Bus which also includes event hub and queues. The template creates the queues and event hubs successfully but some times the authorization rules some how is not created (20% of the time). Below is the trimmed version of the template which I have created after a struggle :P.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "South Central US",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location where all azure resources will be deployed."
            }
        },
        "serviceBusNamespace": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the service bus namespace to create."
            }
        },
        "queueName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the queue to create."
            }
        },
        "hubName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the event hub to create."
            }
        },
        "messagingSku": {
            "type": "int",
            "minValue": 1,
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The SKU version."
            }
        },
        "queueMaxSizeInGB": {
            "type": "int",
            "minValue": 1,
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "maxValue": 16,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The queue max size."
            }
        },
        "partitionCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "minValue": 2,
            "defaultValue": 2,
            "maxValue": 32,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The partition count of event hub."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "queueSize": "[mul(parameters('queueMaxSizeInGB'),1024)]",
        "managePolicy": "ManagePolicy",
        "sendPolicy": "SendPolicy",
        "listenPolicy": "ListenPolicy"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespace')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "messagingSku": "[parameters('messagingSku')]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('queueName')]",
                    "type": "Queues",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "path": "[parameters('queueName')]",
                        "maxSizeInMegabytes": "[variables('queueSize')]"
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('managePolicy')]",
                            "type": "authorizationRules",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Rights": [
                                    "Send",
                                    "Listen",
                                    "Manage"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('sendPolicy')]",
                            "type": "authorizationRules",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Rights": [
                                    "Send"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('listenPolicy')]",
                            "type": "authorizationRules",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Rights": [
                                    "Listen"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('hubName')]",
                    "type": "EventHubs",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "path": "[parameters('hubName')]",
                        "partitionCount": "[parameters('partitionCount')]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "queueManagePolicy": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('queueName'),variables('managePolicy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        },
        "queueSendPolicy": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('queueName'),variables('sendPolicy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        },
        "queueListenPolicy": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('queueName'),variables('listenPolicy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        }
    }
}
```

Is somebody also having the same issue or I am missing something silly? Is there a fix?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it throw any error when the authorization rules not created?

Comment: got this template in github and seems to work alright. check it out https://github.com/sjkp/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/blob/master/Azure.ARM.ServiceBus/Templates/DeploymentTemplate.json

Comment: @JackZeng Since I have defined outputs it does throw errors. Without that it works fine

Comment: @Aravind Let me check and try that

Comment: @Aravind: Still no luck. There still seems to be a problem while creating the auth rules :(

Comment: oh ok .. but the outputs work only if the template gets executed successfully. since you mentioned that the template works fine without the outputs am wondering how..

Comment: Strangely Powershell does not give the error if I don't define the outputs. On the other hand if I check on portal.azure.com I do find that the auth rule execution status is displayed (success or failure)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MS helped me resolve the issue. The problem was that the authorization rules were getting created in parallel which RM does not like. The way to fix it is to simply create the SAS tokens one by one. Below is the consistently working ARM template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "South Central US",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location where all azure resources will be deployed."
            }
        },
        "serviceBusNamespace": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the service bus namespace to create."
            }
        },
        "queueName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the queue to create."
            }
        },
        "hubName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the event hub to create."
            }
        },
        "messagingSku": {
            "type": "int",
            "minValue": 1,
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The SKU version."
            }
        },
        "queueMaxSizeInGB": {
            "type": "int",
            "minValue": 1,
            "defaultValue": 1,
            "maxValue": 16,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The queue max size."
            }
        },
        "partitionCount": {
            "type": "int",
            "minValue": 2,
            "defaultValue": 2,
            "maxValue": 32,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The partition count of event hub."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "queueSize": "[mul(parameters('queueMaxSizeInGB'),1024)]",
        "managePolicy": "ManagePolicy",
        "sendPolicy": "SendPolicy",
        "listenPolicy": "ListenPolicy"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('serviceBusNamespace')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "messagingSku": "[parameters('messagingSku')]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('queueName')]",
                    "type": "Queues",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "path": "[parameters('queueName')]",
                        "maxSizeInMegabytes": "[variables('queueSize')]"
                    },
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('managePolicy')]",
                            "type": "authorizationRules",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Rights": [
                                    "Send",
                                    "Listen",
                                    "Manage"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('sendPolicy')]",
                            "type": "authorizationRules",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'))]",
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'), '/authorizationRules/', variables('managePolicy'))]",
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Rights": [
                                    "Send"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                            "name": "[variables('listenPolicy')]",
                            "type": "authorizationRules",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'))]",
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'), '/authorizationRules/', variables('managePolicy'))]",
                                "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),'/queues/',parameters('queueName'), '/authorizationRules/', variables('sendPolicy'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "Rights": [
                                    "Listen"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
                    "name": "[parameters('hubName')]",
                    "type": "EventHubs",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/', parameters('serviceBusNamespace'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "path": "[parameters('hubName')]",
                        "partitionCount": "[parameters('partitionCount')]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "queueManagePolicy": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('queueName'),variables('managePolicy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        },
        "queueSendPolicy": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('queueName'),variables('sendPolicy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        },
        "queueListenPolicy": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules',parameters('serviceBusNamespace'),parameters('queueName'),variables('listenPolicy')),'2015-08-01').primaryConnectionString]"
        }
    }
}
```